# Installing SP2010 on Windows 8.1

Tags: 2010, deployment, windows

Did anyone have a successful story of installing SP2010 on Windows 8.1? So far I'm stuck at installing .net 3.5. It gives me an error:

> 0x800F0906 could not install .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and
>   3.0)

I even tried a standalone installer for .net 3.5, but the error is the same.

When trying to use this command in command prompt

> dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:netfx3 /source....

I receive an error saying that the source files are missing. I know that the source is not missing, because i'm looking at them right now in the file system. I've tryied mounting ISO's with windows 8.1 manually and firing dism command against mounted sources, but the error was the same ("no source files were found")

There might be a problem with WSUS, but I have two of my colleagues with the same OS setup who didn't have any problems that i described above. The only difference is that they have Windows 8 ad I have 8.1

The stuff I found on the Internet was of no help so far.

Comment: Keep in mind neither SharePoint 2010 or 2013 support installation on Windows 8.1.

Comment: hi, Trevor. Have you got a link that says it? I know that you can't install SharePoint 2013 on Windows Server 2012 R2, but I could not find anything preventing me from installing SP 2010 on Windows 8.1

Comment: I found this link that says that SharePoint 2010 R2 can be installed on Windows Server 2012 R2 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2724471). So it's only logical that I can install SP 2010 R2 on Windows 8.1 as well. This is just for development purposes, of course. I don't approve of this method at all, but  we don't have spare OS licences for Windows Server :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

> If installing the .NET Framework 3.5 on demand or enabling it in
>   Control Panel fails, you may get one of the following error messages:
>
> •**0x800f0906**: “Windows couldn't connect to the Internet to download
>   necessary files. Make sure that you're connected to the Internet, and
>   click Retry to try again.”
>
> •0x800F081F: “The changes could not be completed. Please reboot your
>   computer and try again.”

**resolution**

> These messages may be displayed for the following reasons:
>
> •Your computer is not connected to the Internet. Please connect, and
>   then retry the operation.
>
> If you cannot connect to the Internet, you can enable the .NET
>   Framework 3.5 by using the Deployment Image Servicing and Management
>   (DISM) command-line tool and specifying the installation media (ISO
>   image or DVD) you installed Windows 8 from.
>
> **1.** In Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012, open a Command Prompt window with administrative credentials (that is, choose Run as
>   administrator).
>
> **2.** To install the .NET Framework 3.5 from installation media located in the D:\sources\sxs directory, use the following command:
>
> DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess
>   /Source:d:\sources\sxs
>
> where:
>
> ■/Online targets the operating system you're running (instead of an
>   offline Windows image).
>
> ■/Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 specifies that you want to enable
>   the .NET Framework 3.5.
>
> ■/All enables all parent features of the .NET Framework 3.5.
>
> ■/LimitAccess prevents DISM from contacting Windows Update.
>
> ■/Source specifies the location of the files needed to restore the
>   feature (in this example, the D:\sources\sxs directory).
>
> For more information about DISM parameters and options, see How to
>   Enable or Disable Windows Features
>
> •You are using a local source, but the network location is
>   inaccessible or doesn’t have the right content. Install the .NET
>   Framework 3.5 from installation media as described in the previous
>   bullet point.
>
> •Your administrator has configured your computer to use Windows Server
>   Update Services (WSUS) instead of Windows Update for servicing. Ask
>   your administrator to enable the policy to use Windows Update instead
>   of WSUS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've read this article. I've managed to force "DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:d:\sources\sxs" to work. I think, the problem was that I was probably using iso for Windows 8 instead of 8.1. Also, I've restarted my PC 2 times and disabled firewall and what not. So, I'm not sure what helped in the end. But I am yet to install SharePoint 2010. If SharePoint 2010 will be installed with no problem - i'll gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem.. after trying all the options and not getting the installed .net framework i formatted my machine and installed fresh OS and then updated feature.